# Making a LINQ query better

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a hard time getting the LINQ-syntax.. How can I do this command in a better way?

```
var user = (from u in context.users
            where u.email.Equals(email)
            select u).Single();
var pinToUser = (from ptu in context.pintousers
                 where ptu.user_id.Equals(user.id)
                 select ptu).Single();
var pin = (from p in context.pins
           where p.idpin.Equals(pinToUser.pin_idpin)
           select p).Single();

return pin;
```

As you can see, there's a table user, a table pintouser and a table pin. Pintouser references user and pin. Is it possible to write something short like "user.pintouser.pin"? I think I have the navigation properties all set up but I'm not sure how to use them properly or if I could make them better by modifying them.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You could probably rewrite this as a single query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use joins to rewrite everything as a single clean query. If I read your queries properly, this should give you the correct result:

```
var pin = (from u in context.users
          join ptu in context.pintousers on u.id equals ptu.user_id
          join p in context.pins on ptu.pin_idpin equals p.idpin
          where u.email == email
          select p).Single();
```

Keep in mind, though, that if this query returns anything other than a single result your code will throw an Exception.

If you want to handle the possibility of getting one or no rows then you should use `SingleOrDefault()`.

If you want to handle the possiblity of getting any number of rows then you should really use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you, it works and this gave me some insight in using join!

Comment: Original query returns a single pin.  Yours returns an IQueryable or some such.

Comment: @recursive - You're right, I was focused on the joins and forgot the call to Single(). Fixed.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be "context.pins on ptu.pin_idpin equals p.idpin". They are the other way in your example.

Comment: @Phil - Order doesn't matter when specifying the join criteria. It can be written either way.

Comment: @Justin - I actually had to change it in vs because it complained that they were out of context that way. It worked when I switched the order? Maybe was related to something else though.

Comment: @Phil - Interesting. I updated the answer but I have no idea why that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you have your foreign-key relationship set righ in your database, Linq-to-Sql should have the joins for you automatically:

```
var pin = (from u in context.users 
      where u.email == email 
      select u.pintouser.pin).Single();
```

which means you can reduce this to:

```
var pin = context.users.Where(u=>u.email == email)
                       .Select(u=>u.pintouser.pin)
                       .Single();
```

(UPDATE Note: I had originally suggested the following, which is much shorter, but I believe it will cause two round-trips to the database)

```
var pin = context.users.Single(u=>u.email == email).Single().pintouser.pin;
```

Now, the `.pintouser.pin` is safe, because the `Single()` will always return a `user` object (or throw an exception).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `join`, as @JustinNiessner points out, but this is another way to write your query.

```
var user = context.users.Single(u => u.email == email);
var pinToUser = context.pintousers.Single(ptu => ptu.user_id == user.id);
var pin = context.pins.Single(p => p.idpin == pinToUser.pin_idpid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have navigation properties, might as well use them:

```
Pin pin =
(
  from u in context.Users
  where u.email == email
  from ptu in u.pintousers
  let p = ptu.pin
  select p
).Single();
```

Comment: as you might declare a variable inside a loop, creating one variable per loop iteration... "let" allows you to declare a variable for each row in the query.